# Not able to access the optional delegate of swift class into objective c project

Tags: swift, delegates, datasource, spreadsheet, objc-bridging-header

I am using swift pod file into my objective c project and when I tried to set the delegate of the swift class , I see no where the data source and delegate. I was not able to access it. Can anyone tell me the reason why I was not able to access it.

What are another things of swift that we cannot access?

Answer (score 0):

In swift file where that delegate is defined, Check for @objc before protocol or delegate definition if you can download the source of the library you are using, It should be there to access that protocol in objective c code,

Swift Delegate Definition should be like this

```
@objc protocol AnyControllerDelegate {

}
```